# Why does a classic envelope detector produce a negative voltage for some periods, when high frequencies are put in?

Tags: rf, diodes, spice, ngspice

I'm playing around in ngspice & trying to understand envelope detectors for ham radio.

I'm pumping 150Mhz into the circuit described below - I'm expecting it to go positive in proportion to amplitude + frequency. After a bit, it goes negative. Whats happening here?

Consider this circuit:

[image: diode detector]

- 150Mhz 2V sine wave input, 50ohms impedance
- D1N4148 diode
- 100pF smoother capacitor
- 500k bleed/load resistance

Spice input I'm using / working on:

```
Detector CIRCUIT
.model D1N4148 D (IS=0.1pA, RS=16 CJO=2pF TT=12N BV=100 IBV=0.1pA)

v1 1 0 sin(0 2 150MEG)

rSOURCE 2 1 50

d1 2 3 D1N4148

c1 3 0 100p

rLOAD 3 0 500k

.control
tran 5us 50ms
run
write kek.raw v(3)
quit
.endc
.end
```

Gives me this:

[image: transient analysis]

Note the negative sections.

How does a diode detector go negative like this? how do I stop it?

Comment: The 1N4148 diode has a frequency limit of about 50 MHZ at 50% duty cycle. You need a UHF diode for this to work.

Comment: Yes but he was getting < 1nV output  > Warning Will Rogers.

Comment: Don't forget to check the *scale* of the Y-axis: it's between 1e-9 and 8e-10. That should tell you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

v1 1 0 sin(0 2 150MEG)
...
tran 5us 50ms

=====

What's wrong with this picture?

==

The sampling time is violating Shannon's Law.  **Measurement error.**

What is the diode spec?

- Rectification efficiency \$V_{HF} = 2 V, f = 100 MHz ~~~ η_r = 45 \text{%}\$

It won't work well because recovery time is 4ns with 100 Ohm load and yours is only 500k.

Although Cj=2pF is ok. ( even though max in the datasheet is 4pF )

As @Sparky256 said try a UHF diode.

These have faster recovery time than 8ns on a signal with a 6.7ns cycle time.
 This is why efficiency is poor at 100MHz and worse at 150MHz.

T[ry a Falstad simulator.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%200%205e-12%2089.03963197220334%2050%205%2048%0Av%20160%20272%20160%20224%200%201%20150000000%202%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20160%20272%20336%20272%200%0Ad%20224%20160%20336%20160%201%201.505904783%0Aw%20336%20128%20336%20160%200%0Ac%20336%20160%20336%20224%200%201e-10%200.9422357234103714%0Aw%20336%20160%20416%20160%200%0Aw%20336%20272%20416%20272%200%0Ar%20416%20160%20416%20272%200%20500000%0Ax%20451%20232%20481%20235%204%2016%20load%0Ar%20160%20224%20160%20176%200%2050%0Aw%20224%20160%20224%20128%200%0AR%20192%20176%20256%20224%201%202%2010000000%202.5%202.5%203.141592653589793%200.5%0A160%20224%20160%20160%20160%200%2020%2010000000000%0Ag%20160%20144%20144%20144%200%0Ag%20160%20272%20160%20288%200%0Al%20336%20224%20336%20272%200%205e-9%20-0.0000018844716809899519%0Ao%200%20256%200%204098%202.5%200.00009765625%200%202%200%203%0Ao%207%20256%200%204866%200.9641404457003497%200.0001%200%202%207%203%0Ao%202%20256%200%2012545%200.0001%200.00027301552629102285%201%202%202%203%0A)  Limited parameters no custom parts. You make the passive part models and LOGIC, OA's have 0 Ohms out. Same with Voltage sources.

Press Reset anytime.

Comment: It was indeed Shannon's Law, thanks! I upped the resolution of the simulation and let it run for a few minutes and the waveform looks much better.

Comment: Falstad's sim is much faster  real time , fast or slow motion > options> other options> sampling time or mouse wheel over scope trace